# How can I get video source from movie website

Tags: url, video, download

I want extract video source for example for this movie.
https://www.cda.pl/video/53956781/vfilm

There are hidden video sources. And there is something like security steps to unable do it.
I opened it in firefox with Video Download Helper and I got:

```
headers 
[...
]
id  
network-probe:5f8a4b2c
isPrivate   
false
length  
831760944
pageUrl 
https://www.cda.pl/video/53956781/vfilm
referrer    
https://www.cda.pl/video/53956781/vfilm
running 
0
status  
active
tabId   
36
thumbnailUrl    

https://icdn.2cda.pl/vid/premium/539567/frames/620x365/e86f6548543225cf0f1b61f1e9d730be.jpg
title   
Istnienie (2013) Lektor PL 720p - CDA
topUrl  
https://www.cda.pl/video/53956781/vfilm
type    
video
url 
https://vwaw607.cda.pl/539567/v_lq_lq5250559bd547af6bad2eb78dacaf5df4.mp4
urlFilename 
v_lq_lq5250559bd547af6bad2eb78dacaf5df4
```

So there is an video source but If I go to `https://vwaw607.cda.pl/539567/v_lq_lq5250559bd547af6bad2eb78dacaf5df4.mp4`
it says video cannot be loaded. File is damaged

Could you give me an idea how to extract video url. Thanks

Comment: You have the video URL already, just that the video itself is copy-protected by the [PlayReady](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/playready/packaging/content-encryption) DRM system.

Comment: So i cant play it on my video player? I have to download it (i can) and then host this video by myself?

Comment: No. The file bytes are **changed** to make it unplayable by normal video players, the un-encryption side will "undo" these changes if using the correct key. You can email the film site to ask for their key or you can try find a different MP4 file of the same film elsewhere.